# PHP - Split html tags keeping delimiters

Tags: php, html

I use this code to split my html code into 3 `trs`:

```
$string = '<tr><td> Total 1 </td><td>779,00</td></tr><tr><td> Total 2 </td><td>867,25</td></tr><tr><td> Total 3 </td><td>939,00</td></tr>';

$result = array_filter(explode('</tr>', str_replace('<tr>','',$string)));
echo htmlspecialchars($result[0], ENT_QUOTES)."<br /><br />";
echo htmlspecialchars($result[1], ENT_QUOTES)."<br /><br />";
echo htmlspecialchars($result[2], ENT_QUOTES)."<br /><br />";
```

shows me that the tr tags are removed, how can I edit it to keep my tr tags ?

I want only a code modification to split my html into 3 tr Tags

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP exploding a string while keeping delimiters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749178/php-exploding-a-string-while-keeping-delimiters)

Comment: @Nijraj Gelani: It's not the same Problem, my code is much shorter and have only to split the tr tags. 
I have also tried the code in the link but It don't returns the wanted result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for this, Hope it will work for you ...

```
$string = '<tr><td> Total 1 </td><td>779,00</td></tr><tr><td> Total 2 </td><td>867,25</td></tr><tr><td> Total 3 </td><td>939,00</td></tr>';
$result = array_filter(explode('</tr>',$string));
$newArray =array();
foreach($result as $val)
{
    $newArray[] = $val.'</tr>';
}
echo htmlspecialchars($newArray[0], ENT_QUOTES)."<br /><br />";
echo htmlspecialchars($newArray[1], ENT_QUOTES)."<br /><br />";
echo htmlspecialchars($newArray[2], ENT_QUOTES)."<br /><br />";
?>
```

This will output:

```
<tr><td> Total 1 </td><td>779,00</td></tr>

<tr><td> Total 2 </td><td>867,25</td></tr>

<tr><td> Total 3 </td><td>939,00</td></tr>
```

Comment: Any other solution by editing the line `$result = array_filter(explode('</tr>',$string));` ??

Comment: @Bizboss I'm also looking for another solution, I'll let you know when i got any other method to do this ...